# Error in installing 'qd' library! How do we read or manipulate the Key file for LS Dyana?

Tags: python, input, text-extraction, data-extraction

**Goal:** I have .Key file for preprocessing data file for LS Dyna simulation. From that .Key file, I want to extract certain node numbers lying under certain Part ID (PID).

In order to achieve above goal, I got to know that there is a one python library named 'qd' (https://qd-cae.github.io/qd-cae-python/build/html/qd_cae_dyna_KeyFile.html) which helps to manipulate the key files and extract certain lines according to the Keyword.

However, when I wrote `from qd.cae.dyna import *`, I got an error `ModuleNotFoundError: from qd.cae.dyna import *`. Therefore, I tried to install `qd` in python using pip `pip install qd`, but I got an error and at the end, this library could not be installed.

My question is:
(1) How can we install `qd` library in python through Anaconda?
(2) Is there any available python tools or library to read and extract some parameters from the Key files?

Answer (score 0):

Try using python 3.7 or less. Newer versions of python don't support library package.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).